# OutOfMemoryError when trying to read huge CSV file from assets (open only in my device where i test code but not in other devices)

Tags: java, android

This is my code for `CSV` file read. My file is open on my testing device where I test my code while creatin `CSV` file but other devices show error. In this I'm reading three lines heading is English, Punjabi and time. I want to read a huge `CSV` file by Java. It includes 75,000,000 lines. The problem is, even though I am using maximum `xms` and `xmx` limits, I'm getting:

> Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError(GC overhead limit exceeded)

And it shows this line causes the error:

```
try {
     InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(getAssets()
     .open(value.concat(".csv")), encoding);
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(is);
      reader.readLine();
      String line;
      StringTokenizer st = null;
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // Log.d("hahaha", line);
            st = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
            // attributes
            addToList(st.nextToken(), st.nextToken());
             new java.util.Timer().schedule(
                 new java.util.TimerTask() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                     highlightText();
                 }
              },
           Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()) * 1000
        );
       }
       reader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
     Log.d("hahaha", e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: 75 Million Lines * n characters in each line. Do you have enough memory in the device? Why do you want to hold all that information in the list? Any specific reason?

Comment: public void addToList(String english, String punjabi) {
//        Log.d("hahaha", english);

        Map<String, String> datum = new HashMap<String, String>(2);
        datum.put("title", punjabi);
        datum.put("subtitle", english);
        data.add(datum);


    }

Comment: Any one have idea for me??

Answer (score 0):

Enable large heap in your manifest:

```
<application
        .
        .
        android:largeHeap="true"
        .
        .>
```